# How to disable shardsWhitelist, I am getting Following error

Tags: solr, lucene, sharding, solrcloud, solr7

So when I add shards in RawQueryParameter of Solr Admin I get following error

```
**error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
      "msg":"HttpShardHandlerFactory shardsWhitelist not configured but required (in lieu of ZkController 
       and ClusterState) when using the 'shards' parameter. set -Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true to 
       disable shards whitelist checks",
    "code":403}}**
```

I want to disable it but didn't found anything useful which is helpful
Please let me know how I  can disable it

I don't want to specify shards like

```
<str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:localhost:8080/solr/test,localhost:8080/solr/test2}</str>
```

just want to disable it

Comment: You need to give the argument `-Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true` when Solr is launched (it's given as an argument to the JVM). Exactly how you do that depends on how you're starting Solr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it as an argument while starting the solr as below.

```
-Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true
```

Also alternative option is you can add as
`solr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true` to `solr.in.sh` file,

which is found at the path `"...\solr-VERSION\bin"`